# How to make a ListView in android?

Tags: android

I need an organized way to organize my app and buttons are starting to look sloppy in my opinion. Below is my code. I have the XML set up to a List View. Not sure if it is right or not.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/species" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/species" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code. I didn't change it yet,, except for the imports from previous attempts to do this.

```
package com.apw.listview.test;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;

public class Species extends Activity
{


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.species);

    }



    }
```

Comment: Try looking for a tutorial, people is not here to code for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two types of list views in Android:
1.Basic List Views.
2.Custom List Views.

**Basic List Views**
These are the listviews that does not requires any additional layout for list view generation.
You can implement it using link:
http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

**Custom List Views**
This type of List views requires additional layout and custom list adapters to set up for implementation.
You can implement it using a link:
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/listview

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a reference to your ListView and then bind it to data with an adapter. Add this at the end of your `onCreate()` method:

```
String[] array = new String[] {"cat", "dog", "mouse"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.species);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Consider completing some of the tutorials on Android's [Developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) to walk you through this.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could have provided more information on what you want in your listview ...
Anyway you can follow this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/
It will provide you with several examples about listview.

To make it simple you need a list, an array or a database, what ever structure you want with your data.

You need to use an interface between your data and your list ( ArrayAdapter, CursorAdapter or your own Adapter base on Base Adapter) to which you give your data

And then whenever you modify your data set you notify your adapter through

```
myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```